# Need help which deciphering 64 bit Intel Assembly instructions to C

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I have a function:

```
long foo(long x, long y, long z);
```

I'm given this assembly output from GCC and I'm trying to figure out what's 
happening convert that to C function.

I'm new to assembly and don't know what's going on at all here.

foo:

```
subq   %rdx %rsi
imulq  %rsi %rdi 
movq   %rsi %rax 
salq   $63  %rax
sarq   $63  %rax
xorq   %rdi %rax
```

x,y,z are passed into registers %rdi, %rsi, & %rdx respectively

Comment: You didn't make clear what it is you need help with. Do you know what `subq` does? If so, were you able to translate the first instruction to equivalent C? If so, what did you get? If not, what was the issue with doing so?

Comment: hint: the shifts broadcast the low bit of rax to every bit in rax.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407437/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-count-set-bits-at-a-position-or-lower/34410357#34410357) also uses an arithmetic shift as a bit-broadcast, but uses it to conditionally zero the result of something else, not to XOR it.

Comment: In response to what I need help with, I don't know where to start.

Comment: you should start with [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the x86_64 calling convention for SystemV ABI conformant systems (e.g. POSIX/linux) to map the given registers to the arguments in the function prototype. Although this was given as a pre-condition, it's helpful to consult a reference that explains this in more detail: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64

---

Also, because the code uses `%rdi`, we *know*:

1. This is *not* windows because the windows ABI doesn't use `rdi` for any of its "passed in register" arguments
2. We know we're using "AT&T syntax" [because of the `%` prefix] and *not* "Intel syntax" ...
3. ... so the destination register is the *rightmost* on an instruction.

The "q" suffix on all instructions means "quadword" (i.e. 64 bits). Under windows, `long` is 32 bits [go figure :-)], so, again, this is definitely SysV because under windows, the first instruction would a 32 bit one, using the 32 bit register names [*and* the actual registers would be different]:

```
    subl    %edx %esi
```

---

Most of the asm instructions should be intuitive.

Note that because of `long`, the operations are working on *signed* integers.

Combining all this, here is a sample program:

```
// x86_64 calling convention:
//   arg 0: %rdi
//   arg 1: %rsi
//   arg 2: %rdx
//   arg 3: %rdx
//   arg 4: %r8
//   arg 5: %r9

long
foo(long x,long y,long z)
// x -- %rdi
// y -- %rsi
// z -- %rdx
{
    long ret;

    // subq   %rdx %rsi
    y -= z;

    // imulq  %rsi %rdi
    x *= y;

    // movq   %rsi %rax
    ret = x;

    // salq   $63  %rax
    ret <<= 63;

    // sarq   $63  %rax
    ret >>= 63;

    // xorq   %rdi %rax
    ret ^= x;

    return ret;
}
```

---

[Prefaced by the `movq`] the two shift operations are a slight "trick".

The first one `salq` left shifts bit 0 into bit 63, which is the *sign* bit. The `sarq` is an *arithmetic* right shift that shifts in the *sign* bit on the left. The net effect is that all bits will be set to the sign bit.

So, this is equivalent to:

```
xor_mask = (x & 1) ? -1 : 0;
```

Comment: The last line of the question indicates they were given the calling convention arg->register mapping.  Also, you might want to be clear that gcc with AT&T syntax does work on Windows, and that it's the `%`  that tells us AT&T syntax, and the use of RDI to pass the first arg tells us we're using the everything-but-Windows SystemV ABI.

Comment: Oh also, the Windows x86-64 ABI has 32-bit `long`.  But yeah, you don't really need to spend too much time identifying the calling convention, since that's given in the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've reworked the answer a bit based on your comments

Comment: The SystemV ABI doesn't necessarily imply POSIX.  Any random embedded or custom OS can (and probably does) use it.  So SysV -> POSIX is only true if you consider only major desktop/server OSes, because all the non-Windows ones are more or less POSIX.  Other than that, the first part is now great; would upvote again :)

Comment: Oh BTW, I think you have a mistake in your final line: the return value isn't just 0 or -1.  That is XORed with the multiply result, so it's a conditional bitwise-NOT.  Modifying your vars (instead of declaring new vars to hold new values) makes the `x&1` in your final line confusing: It refers to `x` after the modifications from your code block, not the function arg.

Comment: @PeterCordes You sure are holding my feet to the fire on this one :-) I was pressed for time when I posted the original. The `x&1` was intended to be _just_ about the shifts to demystify them. It wasn't intended to include the final xor. I've clarified that a bit. P.S. I had thought of you when I saw that the linked document had "the red zone" in it :-)

Comment: Indeed, pointing out esoteric details is one of my favourite pass-times. :)   The red zone comes up all the time in SO questions about doing something ill-advised with inline asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes _Indeed, pointing out esoteric details is one of my favourite pass-times._ That isn't very Canadian ... Are you a "troublemaker"? :-)