# Avoid unnecessary mov ecx, ecx instruction in bzhi(y, tzcnt(x))

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, bit-manipulation, compiler-optimization

I have a bit position (it's never zero), calculated by using tzcnt and I would like to zero high bits starting from that position.
This is code in C++ and disassembly (I'm using MSVC):

```
auto position = _tzcnt_u64(xxx); 
auto masked =_bzhi_u64(yyy, static_cast<uint32_t>(position));
```

```
tzcnt       rcx,rdx  
mov         ecx,ecx  
bzhi        rax,rbx,rcx
```

BZHI accepts unsigned int as second parameter, but only uses bits [7..0] from rcx, so this 'mov' instruction is unnecessary in my opinion.

I use this to later calculate popcount, so I could also use something like <<(64-position) instead.

Problem is - these two codes have the same execution time, although bzhi should perform faster than sub+shlx, so mov probably makes the difference.

Is there a way to avoid it or is this compiler thing?

Comment: Are you doing a release build?

Comment: @user1937198 Yes, this is in release.

Comment: Hmm, neither gcc, nor clang include this mov, so it does seem an MSVC thing: https://godbolt.org/z/6sP2Yy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an MSVC missed optimization.  GCC/clang can use `bzhi` directly on the output of `tzcnt` for your source.  All compilers have missed optimizations in some cases, but GCC and clang tend to have fewer cases than MSVC.

(And GCC is careful to break [the output dependency of `tzcnt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter) when tuning for Haswell to avoid the risk of creating a loop-carried dependency chain through that false dependency.  Unfortunately GCC still does this with `-march=skylake` which doesn't have a false dep for `tzcnt`, only `popcnt`.  Ironically, GCC doesn't break the "true" dependency for `bsr/bsf` on any CPU.)

Intel documents the 2nd input to `_bzhi_u64` as `unsigned __int32 index`.   (You're making this explicit with a `static_cast` to uint32_t for some reason, but removing the explicit cast doesn't help).  IDK how MSVC defines the intrinsic or handles it internally.

IDK why MSVC wants to do this; I wonder if it's zero-extension to 64-bit inside the internal logic of MSVC's `_bzhi_u64` intrinsic that takes a 32-bit C input but uses a 64-bit asm register.  (`tzcnt`'s output value-range is 0..64 so this zero-extension is a no-op in this case)

---

## Masked popcnt: shift `yyy` instead of masking it

As in [What is the efficient way to count set bits at a position or lower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407437/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-count-set-bits-at-a-position-or-lower), it can be more efficient to just shift out the bits you don't want, instead of zeroing them in-place.  (Although `bzhi` avoids the cost of creating a mask so this is just break-even, modulo differences in which execution ports `bzhi` vs. `shlx` can run on.)  `popcnt` doesn't care where the bits are.

(**FIXME: the C++ and asm are using a right shift, which discards low bits.  I should have used left shift to shift out high bits.**  When I wrote this, I was probably thinking discarding low bits since `tzcnt` counts low zeros in the other input.  Left and right shift perform the same so I'm going to leave the answer as-is for now.)

```
uint64_t popcnt_shift(uint64_t xxx, uint64_t yyy) {
    auto position = _tzcnt_u64(xxx); 
    auto shifted = yyy >> position;
    return _mm_popcnt_u64(shifted);
}
```

[**MSVC on Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJIBspLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiXAJykADqgWE6rR6hiZmln4BanR2Ds5Gbh6c3koq0bQMBMzEBCHGphaKypiqQZnZBLFOru5eilk5eWGFCg2V9tUJtckAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDM9siGWADU4uM6eEZG9gTE9gB0CAvY4gAMAIITUzOY84ut%2BPTbuwfHRwZr5twA%2BgSzAF5GzAoA1q8SHhgBAnvQXu9ZgAPGGkWZgggQj4AT1RPXmAHZZEdZrjZswDERZpFAnQLgARWbvT7IeivAwvCAwqE9BbSeY4vEEok/f6YdAU14uT4IPD0xmo5Fw1rMNTIV4sVoLHQI8aSd67CAk9I9VnjbGHPGzYiYAiDWizXl/fls%2B7iDHku2PZ5vD5%2BHy0givBSiqgEUEuyHMuEIpGzSXo%2B0Go3c1DE/yki0LSnUz3i7hMmF69n3GOEuM%2BvB%2B/kU8Ooi57cbYeNRIK2zm4k1m4gW14rV7utMMjOF4vobN2h1Oh6HUOur5WgPg8fB%2BGBlFozHRrn5y2/P6loWsBRGf7pzMstkcw0rnnrkvJsvI%2BYWWYAPwgVuVys4A4bxtN5rXfPQ9eOQ6Oe4x0hb510kKdERnWE52nSEIyXXNTwLU0XEITcXG3MVuwPbNjzzM8f1LSUb3Me8ICUAhUIIABaV8j1mAB6BirxI2ZqIoqjEMbT8W2/a1f31QdHSOEY%2BlYEARgAVhGUhTBGfYZNQCSdDkORZgUAYhnOCZOBkggJIU3VSD%2BEBxnGTYzMsqzrMscSRm4GS5IU0glJGGSFBAfZSH0%2BTRNIOBYCQNAjB8PB2DICgIGC0LwpAAA3ZAfB8V44uSV5JDeKEXlIKgwoIdwPIgFwDJk1DaGyZEJN00hgqMLQCAAeVoVhKt80gsB%2BUR2BK9q8BNUo4swDy2swKESkJUZqrWZQetYPAXGICq9CwKq9I2IxVr6Gh6CYNgOB4fhBGEUQUFUmQhHmjzID6VAfHSYbqIayQ2OyZAkEOAA1AANSR3OKUoNAgawmlMTgrG0Kp4kScJfATdIQcEbUgkhmoPBaf70nKRp9HyQRUhKTG2hRro0ckeoKgRsGZRyYnockSQ%2Bg0wZhi4MSJOk2SetcrLuEtBQEtmVLPE2DLZggXBCBIG9xjB2Y9BCsL3Gl185bO6Q9JKoyTLMizrL1szbIkhzOba1z3M87zNf8mAoBtiAgtQBXwvIShosVjxgAxSScrygrKGKtqyoq1aasdur6Calqeo6kRgG6tr8H6tRBuG5zRvG/KQ%2BmuznLmhalowSa1uWTacroRgWG6g6BDJ46xDVi6XCuiAbruoIHoa8Y2J%2BIYdnGckEF%2BAB3ZRWD%2BtIgk0bRKfB2wOih7pYdrOgZ6RmJ59RvGMbKNoZ/xgGMiJjeSbx3ecbCKmj7iTfX36Zn9rZqTHK5iSoQADnMaiXlmYBkGQWYMSbEkmLCWRBiDKzhPLGKSsJgM1VjIOQGtfJa1MuZfW%2BshBGxkhtSSXknKKQkubLyPlDLW3gPbFAjtoERVdlQ92KA66cH2Mwn2rB8rEEKgHZyQdiCtWqrVeqkdWrORjl1UYIi%2BoEzwCnHq6dkATSzvQGabU86LV4ctIu3l1ql22hXPaXBeACHGEIWOp0EHnTzs3Vu90JKPS7tRHub1kyDwUCPVgY8igT0BsDc%2BoNZ6026N4NewRfGIzhsjY%2B0NkieKkXQLGuRQlU23nEq%2BnQomWGpgk0IfjMkBKSOYRmmkWa3zshzfBLlX4fy/rzaYsdZhMM2PsRpID8BgIgXLOh4VpbjHRCpcx6tLbIL6AgTAzAsAeBbpg%2By2CQC4JNs5M2igLYkNEn0bWaD0HWSmeMZ%2BptCGDMMo/X68yCFuQOas0gg0OGT24EAA%3D%3D)

```
;; MSVC 19.24 -O2 -arch:AVX2  (to enable BMI for andn)
;; also clang10.0 -O3 -march=haswell  makes this asm
unsigned __int64 popcnt_shift(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64) PROC
        tzcnt   rax, rcx
        shrx    rax, rdx, rax
        popcnt  rax, rax
        ret     0
```

3 total uops for the front end = very good for overall throughput when mixed with other surrounding code.

Back-end bottlenecks: 2 uops for port 1 (tzcnt and popcnt) on Intel CPUs.  (shrx runs on port 0 or port 6, as a single uop.  Enabling AVX2 which apparently enables BMI2 for MSVC is important, otherwise it will use 3-uop `shr rax, cl`)
Critical path latency:

- from `yyy` to result: 1 for SHRX, 3 for popcnt = 4 cycles
- from `xxx` to result: 3 for TZCNT plus the above = 7 cycles

Unfortunately GCC is over-cautious about breaking false dependencies, costing extra front-end bandwidth.  (But no extra back-end cost)

```
# GCC10.1
        xor     eax, eax          # could have just done tzcnt rdi,rdi
        tzcnt   rax, rdi
        shrx    rsi, rsi, rax
        xor     eax, eax          # pointless: RAX was already part of the dep chain leading to this.
        popcnt  rax, rsi          # GCC7.5 shifts into RAX for popcnt rax,rax to avoid this dep-breaking xor.
        ret
```

## Lower latency alternatives without `tzcnt`

(But more uops, potentially worse front-end throughput.  Back-end execution port pressure benefits depend on surrounding code.)

BMI1 has some bithack instructions to do stuff like isolate the lowest set bit, all 1 uop with single-cycle latency on Intel.  (AMD Zen runs them as 2 uops, 2 cycle latency: [uops.info](https://www.uops.info/table.html?search=bls&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_HSW=on&cb_SKX=on&cb_ICL=on&cb_ZEN%2B=on&cb_ZEN2=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_base=on&cb_bmi=on))

[`blsmsk`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsmsk) - Get Mask Up to (and including) Lowest Set Bit.  Your original is *not* inclusive of the LSB in `xxx` so unfortunately this mask isn't directly usable.

```
uint64_t zmask_blsmsk(uint64_t xxx, uint64_t yyy) {
    auto mask = _blsmsk_u64(xxx); 
    auto masked = yyy & ~(mask<<1);
    return masked;
}
```

```
;; MSVC -O2 -arch:AVX2  (to enable BMI for andn)
        blsmsk  rax, rcx
        add     rax, rax               ; left shift
        andn    rax, rax, rdx          ; (~stuff) & yyy
        ret     0
```

---

**Or [`blsi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi) will Isolate the Lowest Set Bit.**  That `blsi(xxx) - 1` will create a mask up to and *not* including it.  (For `xxx=1`, we'll get

```
uint64_t zmask2(uint64_t xxx, uint64_t yyy) {
    auto setbit = _blsi_u64(xxx); 
    auto masked = yyy & ~(setbit-1);  // yyy & -setbit
    return masked;
}
```

MSVC compiles as expected, same as clang:

```
        blsi    rax, rcx
        dec     rax
        andn    rax, rax, rdx
        ret     0
```

GCC uses the 2's complement identity to transform it into this, using shorter instructions that can run on any port.  (`andn` can only run on port 1 or port 5 on Haswell / Skylake)

```
;; GCC7.5 -O3 -march=haswell.   Later GCC wastes a `mov` instruction
        blsi    rax, rdi
        neg     rax
        and     rax, rsi
```

**This is 3 uops (not including popcnt) but only has 3 cycle latency from `xxx` -> result, down from 4 for `tzcnt` / `shrx`.**  (All of these are not counting the 3 cycle popcnt latency)  And more importantly, **it doesn't compete for port 1 with `popcnt`.**

(The way MSVC compiles it, to `blsi` + `dec` + `andn`, is 2 uops for port 1 / port 5, though.)

### The optimal choice will depend on the surrounding code, whether throughput or latency is the bottleneck.

If you're doing this for many different masks stored contiguously, SIMD could be effective.  Avoiding `tzcnt` means you can do the lowest-set isolate or mask with bithacks that take a couple instructions.  e.g. `blsi` is `(-SRC) bitwiseAND (SRC)`, as documented in the Operation section of Intel's asm manual.  (Handy place to look up bitmap expressions.)  `blsmsk` is `(SRC-1) XOR (SRC)`

SIMD popcnt can be done with `vpshufb` to do 4-bit parallel LUTs on the two halves of each byte, and you can `vpsadbw` to accumulate horizontally into counts for each element.  (To emulate Ice Lake's AVX512 `vpopcntq`)

Comment: (You're making this explicit with a static_cast to uint32_t... -this is just to remove warning for possible loss of data.

Comment: Blsmsk should do the trick. I can change code a little to include bit at position. So instead of 7 cycles, this should take 5C, at least on Intel.

Comment: @Marka: Ok perfect, `blsmsk` + `andn` + `popcnt` is probably ideal.  Note that "take 5 cycles" only describes *latency* (from the `xxx` input being ready), which isn't always the bottleneck if there's any instruction-level parallelism.  There's no single measure you can just add up across instructions to get a total cost.  [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391).  Latency is *not* a synonym for "performance" in this context.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in latency for this particular case. You have been most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is a compiler thing (as of Visual C++ 2019 00435-60000-00000-AA388).

MSVC's immintrin.h defines

```
__int64 _bzhi_u64(unsigned __int64, unsigned int);
```

following Intel's suboptimal [intrinsic definition](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4330,300,597,6077,2944,2938,5282,112,3865,3864,3868,3141,5152,5214,5205,5335,5344,5282,5225,4201,599&text=_bzhi&techs=Other) that contradicts [command documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bzhi) (all `bzhi` params are of the same size).

clang has in bmi2intrin.h

```
unsigned long long _bzhi_u64(unsigned long long __X, unsigned long long __Y)
```

and so does not see the need to touch the `_tzcnt_u64` result in your code.

I patched MSVC's immintrin.h - to no avail. Sad! Because Peter's sophisticated workarounds do not apply to my case (lzcnt/bzhi, no popcnt).

Comment: Narrow args are allowed to have high garbage.  If MSVC internally thought that `bzhi` would only look at ECX not the full RCX, then it wouldn't need to zero-extend ECX to RCX.  Perhaps the problem is that it thinks `tzcnt` only produces a 32-bit output that might not be zero-extended; if you were going to change anything, I'd look at the `_tzcnt_u64` definition.  (Although as an intrinsic, I'd expect some stuff about it is hard-coded into the compiler, not parsed from the prototype.)